Monitor whether the planned route is being executed
I have a problem and I can't find a solution. I have a route that has several coordinates that would basically be point A to point B point B to point C until the route is completed. I receive coordinate data from a tracker on the route being taken and I want to know how many meters it covered on my total route. I looked for some repositories and example questions, but I didn't find anything similar.
I tried to set up a LineString of the planned route and calculate between two tracker data points whether they are within the route and whether they add up to each other using the Haversine formula.
In brief:
let's think I have this route planned
[31.133174280616576, -83.42203815784336], [31.13192707647258, -83.42157019003105],[31.130689655790633, -83.4211512998921]
and tracker receives 
 [31.133185576131343, -83.42202228254087], [31.132377192472315, -83.42175524389052] 

I want to know how many meters he walked within the planned route. Taking into consideration the intersections of avenues.
I'm trying to solve this with Python using Geopy and the Haversine formula and postgres to which these coordinates are being saved.
For more details, I need the following situation. Let's think that we have a truck that needs to go from one neighborhood to another neighborhood and I, being the owner of the truck, need to know how many percent of what was planned he did, I have the route planned, which let's assume is 2 kilometers, my driver covered 2 kilometers, but only 500 meters were within plan, which would mean he covered 25% of the route planned.
Example code I'm trying to implement to work in parts
    from shapely.geometry import LineString, Point
    from geopy.distance import geodesic
    planned_route = LineString([
        (43.91195105177844, -100.33847318111548),
        (43.912010542805625, -100.33705097257662),
        (43.91203698324306, -100.33570216834944),
        (43.91205020345737, -100.33417902888205),
    ])
    coordinates = [
        (43.91195105177844, -100.33847318111548),
        (43.912010542805625, -100.33705097257662),
    ]
tracker_points = [Point(coord) for coord in coordinates]

        covered_distance = 0
        last_projected_point = None
        
        for point in tracker_points:
            print(planned_route.interpolate(planned_route.project(point)))
            projected_point = planned_route.interpolate(planned_route.project(point))
            if last_projected_point is not None:
                covered_distance += geodesic((last_projected_point.x, last_projected_point.y), (projected_point.x, projected_point.y)).meters
            last_projected_point = projected_point
        
        total_planned_distance = sum(geodesic(planned_route.coords[i], planned_route.coords[i+1]).meters for i in range(len(planned_route.coords) - 1))
        
        percentage_covered = (covered_distance / total_planned_distance) * 100 if total_planned_distance > 0 else 0


Could you please put in a bit more effort and provide a meaningful example? The one you've given probably isn't accurate and minimalistic (see this). Does the tracker guarantee to always have points that follow the planned route? What impact do avenue intersections have on distance calculations? In any case, if you're focusing on the tracker's route distance, the planned one might be irrelevant, IMO. Also, could you include the expected output (which appears to be a number) in your post?

I tried to detail more in the question

Narrow down where you are getting stuck. Do you already have your data in shapely.LineString  or in a database? Do you already have some code? What is the output you want, a percentage?

I'm trying to leave an example in the question
